# Do web crawlers use crawl Angular's routerLink links without page reload?

Tags: angular, routerlink

I use Angular 17 and prerender all of the pages on my site to achieve fast loading times. Also, I use `routerLink` on internal links to prevent page reload on navigation.

Because of this, the user experiences is slightly different behaviour if they go directly to a page (see prerenderd version) or navigate to it by following an internal link (rendered on the browser).

Which behaviour will a web crawler see if they go to my home page and then follow an internal link?